# CRON job not setting up on linux

Tags: module, cron, scheduler, auto, magento-2.3

I have setup the corn command using `crontab -e` command.

> MAILTO=""
>
> ## * * * * * /usr/bin/php7.2 /var/www/vhosts/hostname/httpdocs/bin/magento cron:run --group="test"

I have created module to run CRON job automatically. But it is not working automatically.

Instead when I hit command `php bin/magento cron:run` it works.
I am surprised cron task is performing manually but not automatically.

Comment: Please don't use screenshot, copy paste your output directly in your question using code block.

Comment: Okay. let me edit.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It is working fine now.

The actual issue was with the user setting up the CRON job. I was setting the CRON job with root user. Later I set up the same CRON using developer user having ftp access and it worked perfectly.